# How can specific columns be excluded from results when selecting from INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, information-schema

Here is my previous question on how to iterate a string in SQL Server:

Now how can I specifically select column names?
here is my code for selecting columns:

```
SELECT 'Field '+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ordinal_position) AS varchar(5))+': ' + 
COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_Name = 'SystemDefined' and table_schema = 'schemaAsset'
```

Here is the output:

```
Field 1: Asset_No
Field 2: AssetCategory
Field 3: AssetClassification
Field 4: PurchaseType
Field 5: Department
Field 6: RespPerson
Field 7: Status
Field 8: Location
```

This the output I want when selecting specific column names:

```
Field 1: Asset_No
Field 2: AssetCategory
Field 3: AssetClassification
Field 4: PurchaseType
Field 5: Department
Field 6: RespPerson
Field 7: Status
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `NOT IN` which you can use on the `WHERE` clause to specify for another condition.

```
SELECT...
FROM..
WHERE  table_Name = 'SystemDefined' AND 
       table_schema = 'schemaAsset' AND
       COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('Status',....) --  specify the list of names you
                                          -- don't want to show
```

Comment: Ah yes sir I can use that too, sorry I'm a newbie, thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, you can just use a `WHERE` clause to exclude the column(s) you do not want:

```
SELECT 'Field '
  + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ordinal_position) AS varchar(5))+': ' 
  + COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_Name = 'SystemDefined' 
  and table_schema = 'schemaAsset'
  and COLUMN_NAME <> 'Location'
```

If you have multiple columns, then you can use `NOT IN ('Location', 'etc')`

Comment: Yes I forgot this one to use, because I thought it will not work because the first time i try it there are errors, maybe just syntax error, anyway thanks sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Recommend `sys.columns` instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` ([here's why](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)).

```
SELECT 'Column ' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_id))
  + ': ' + name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'schemaAsset.SystemDefined')
AND name NOT IN ('Location' /* , ... other columns ... */)
ORDER BY column_id; -- because you never know how SQL Server might order
```